# can we use inversion after "then"

Tags: subject-verb-inversion

In the following sentence, the inversion structure has been used because of "**then**" or does it have another reason?

> The first moving pictures were simple "shadow shows" or " shadow plays". **Then *came* the magic lantern which** projected painted glass slides on to a screen.

Actually this was a test in our country's university entrance exam:

The first moving pictures were simple "shadow shows" or " shadow plays". ............... projected painted glass slides on to a screen.

1. Then came the magic lantern which
2. Then the magic lanterns came that
3. the magic lanterns then came to be
4. the magic lanterns then came and was

I looked the answer in the answer sheet and it was the first one. I just wanted to know " do we use the inversion structure after "then"?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U...please source your quote.

Comment: thank you - OK - done

Comment: With _come_ in a historical metaphor, any time phrase allows inversion: _After that, Earlier ..._

Comment: There is absolutely nothing wrong with answer 2. *Magic lantern* and *magic lanterns* are both perfectly fine. The inversion is optional, and this is one of the cases where either *that* or *which* can be used.

Comment: @PeterShor I think the OP has missed a comma there. If there were lots of magic laterns and this was the magic lantern that projected xyz then that would be fine. But that's not what those sentences mean. I think it's actually meant to be *Then came the magic lantern, which*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subject-verb inversion following a fronting adverb/adjective e.g. *"Long was the road to her heart but dearly did I love her."* (Greybeard 2022) was a common practice in Old English which maintained the verb as the second element. It remained common in Middle and early Modern English as an option.

Except for poetic/literary use, the practice dwindled after the 18th century and is now restricted to chiefly locative and existential adverbs, negative adverbs and some fronting prepositional phrases (but not clauses)

- There (existential adv.) are lions in Africa
- Here/there (locative adv.) are the scissors.
- In the garden (locative adv. pp) grew roses and cherry trees. (mildly emphatic: somewhat poetic/formal)
- Never (mildly emphatic: temporal negative adv.) had he seen such a sight. (somewhat
  poetic/formal)
- Nowhere (mildly emphatic: locative negative adv.) was he to be found (somewhat
  poetic/formal)

Temporal adverbs (e.g. **then, in the morning, on Tuesdays, etc**) are currently rarely used with inversion (obviously, other than in interrogatives) and, when they do, they often give a strong poetic flavour.

However, your example, *Then came the magic lantern which projected painted glass slides on to a screen* is one of the few temporal contexts where constant use has maintained a natural feel to the construction, as it has an emphatic quality (Compare "*Only then* did I realise that the gun had been loaded." / "*Then* I realised that the gun had been loaded.")

It is hard to resist telling students to avoid inversion after fronting modifiers as there is only guidance - no rules - and eventually they will become familiar with what sounds normal and what sounds like an overblown 18th century poet.

[Random Idea English](http://random-idea-english.blogspot.com/2014/09/exploring-inversion-and-fronting.html#:%7E:text=Inversion%20is%20often%20used%20in,negative%20adverb%2C%20with%20obligatory%20inversion.) has a good guide to fronting and inversion.

Comment: Taking your examples as (1-5). In (1), there is no inversion. (2-3) are indeed examples of locative/subject-dependent inversion. (4-5) are different, and involve subject-auxiliary inversion, which is a very different thing!

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. *In (1), there is no inversion.* I do hope you are not suggesting that "there" is, in some weird way, a subject... or there are "special rules"...  *(4-5) are different* Are you suggesting that "never", and "nowhere" are not adverbs or that "had he" or "was he" are not inversions?

Comment: "Had he" in "Never had he seen such a sight" is an example of SAI and is different to the subject-dependent locative inversion seen in (2-3). Just for starters, the latter is entirely optional and is a matter of style and information packaging. The former is mandatory, and not using SAI there would be ungrammatical. Compare: *Roses and cherry trees grew in the garden*. (fine) and **Nowhere he was to be found* (ungrammatical). If (1) is locative inversion, what's the uninverted form?

Comment: Thanks: You will note that "Never had he seen such a sight" is revertable: *"He had never seen such a sight"* and "Nowhere was he to be found" -> *"He was to be found nowhere."*

Comment: @Greybeard , thank you very much for your explanation. it was great. Can you tell why other choices are incorrect, for example choice 2, is it because of using "that" or another thing?

Comment: @Mahdi The examination board is being pedantic. In 1., the magic lantern is an uncountable class noun and appropriate as the context is of ideas/concepts - the concept of the magic lantern. In 2, "the magic lanterns" are countable, (countable nouns tend to be real) and it gives the idea that many individual magic lanterns arrived. Personally, as the plural can indicate examples of the class, I can only say that 1. is slightly preferable to 2.

Comment: @Mahdi The other point is that 1. uses "which" and 2 uses "that" - there should be a comma before "which" to indicate that the following clause is non-defining. 2, on the other hand, uses "that" - *that* usually introduces a defining clause (but this is not a "rule") but I don't think that "projected painted glass slides on to a screen." is defining.

Comment: @Greybeard *If the negative phrase is fronted*, though, the subject auxiliary inversion is compulsory. But of course, if it isn't, it isn't. Compare that with the subject-dependent inversion where the inversion is optional *whether or not the phrase is fronted* "Then came the floods" and "Then the floods came".  Notice also that SAI requires *did* when there's no auxiliary. The same's not true of subject-dependent inversion as show above and in the OP's example. Btw, *could* a student avoid inversion after fronting a negative phrase?

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. Is not the auxiliary an adverb? WIKI: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subject–auxiliary_inversion *At no time will Jessica say that.* - Subject-auxiliary inversion with a fronted negative expression. The negative expression is adverbial.

Comment: @Greybeard I don't quite understand what you mean? In your example, the negative preposition phrase (functioning as an Adjunct/Adverbial) is *At no time*, the auxiliary is *will*, the Subject is *Jessica*.

Comment: I've obviously misunderstood. Your point is that whilst some inversion is optional, some is not? The answer was not encyclopaedic but did give a link. This takes up your point (I think).

Comment: @Greybeard The SAI (4-5) isn't optional, the other type (2-3) is.

Comment: We may be at cross purposes here: if there is fronting then there is inversion, if there is not, there is not.

Comment: @Greybeard You can front *here/there/in the garden* with no inversion.